Node.js socket io server disconnects python socket.io client after 30 seconds
Node.js socket io server disconnects python socket.io client after 30 seconds..
server sends this:

0{"sid":"6afJCYzsh1Yz3bh3AAAA","upgrades":[],"pingInterval":25000,"pingTimeout":5000}

am not able to find any other references of how a non nodejs client should respond to keep the connection alive..  nodejs client works well..
Tried with nodejs client, that worked beyond 30 seconds..  only python and c# client that i tried, gets disconnected in 30 seconds..
`import socketio
sio = socketio.Client()`
